# Reusing objects with two hashmap

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I wanted to make a more simple verison of a pool in my app, using two hashmap - one with alive objects, and one with dead.

I have a function that spawns alive objects and places them in an hashmap, and if they die it removes it from the hashmap. This causes a lot of calls to garbage collector and a big ram usage that only grows. Instead I thought of solution, creating two hashmap like that:

```
    ConcurrentHashMap<Point, Mob> spawned = new ConcurrentHashMap<Point,  Mob>();
    ConcurrentHashMap<Point, Mob> died = new ConcurrentHashMap<Point, Mob>();
```

And placing a dead object inside the died hashmap like that for example:

```
        MobSpawnedEntries1 = spawned.entrySet().iterator();
        while (MobSpawnedEntries1.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<Point, Mob> entry = MobSpawnedEntries1.next();
            if(entry.getValue().isDead()){
                died.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                MobSpawnedEntries1.remove();
            }
        }
```

After that in the spawn function, i checked if the "died" hashmap is empty, if its not I just respawned the object and placed it in the spawned hashmap, and also removed it from the died hashmap.

```
    if (diedEntries.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<Point, Mob> entry = diedEntries.next();
        Point p=entry.getKey();
        Mob b=entry.getValue();
        b.Reset();
        p.x=...;
        p.y=...;
        spawned.put(p,b);
        diedEntries.remove();
    }
```

### The problem:

This caused odd bugs such as all entities becoming the same, and changing to the newest spawned entity, when one entitiy dies they all die as well, and stuff like that - like there was connection between all the entities. I thought it was the key so I just created a new Point for each entity instead of placing the old key, but the bug still accured. Why? What is a better solution for this (if there is a need of use in pool ill be happy if someone could show me how - I have never used pool or have any idea how to use it).

Comment: Please post valid code, e.g. `if(entry.isDead()){` isn't valid because `entry` is a `Map.Entry`.

Comment: @AndyTurner sorry, fixed.

Comment: @AndyTurner Point is a normal point.. and Mob is a class I made with many features and bitmap.

Comment: Without access to your implementation of  `Point` and `Mob` it is very hard to help, but I would guess: maybe you did (not) implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in those two classes? And maybe you have some static fields in there, that should not be static?

Comment: Do you need to keep the dead values in a `Map`? Are you setting the coordinates of the `Point` to the same value, e.g. `0, 0`? This would mean that you're only ever keeping one thing in the died map, since you're always adding values with the same key. A `Queue` of some sort might be an alternative.

Comment: @EddyG I didn't and there are no static. It didn't happen only with Mob, you can replace Mob with the built in Rect, the same bug appeared there when I tried to make an animation of rectangles coming from the left outside the screen and moving to the right outside the screen, when a rectangle was fully outside I just placed him in the dead hashmap and tries to respawn him, but for some odd reason the rectangle would disappear mid way when another rectangle went outside the screen.

Comment: @AndyTurner no, I remove it from the dead hashmap after respawning it, and when I respawn I change the x,y to where it would be when it spawned.